# Google Maps return to origin

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using a pretty basic Google Maps api and I'm wondering if we can have a "Go back to origin" type of button so that we are redirected back to the original position (and maybe zoom?) as to refresh the map.

[You can find a jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wQM8z/)

#### Sample Code

**Current Javascript**

```
function initialize() {
        /* ----- Variables ---------------------------------- */
        var myLat = 46.331302;
        var myLong = -72.554991;
        var iconURL = 'img/logo-map-marker-large.png';
        var myClose = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif";
        var bbl_bg = "url('img/tipbox.gif') no-repeat";
        /* ----- Scripted ----------------------------------- */
        var loc,map,marker,infobox;
        loc=new google.maps.LatLng(myLat,myLong);
        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
          {zoom:15,center:loc,mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP});
        marker=new google.maps.Marker({
          map:map,position:loc,
          icon:iconURL,visible:true});
        infobox=new InfoBox({
          content:document.getElementById("infobox"),
          disableAutoPan:false,
          maxWidth:150,
          pixelOffset:new google.maps.Size(-140,0),
          zIndex:null,
          boxStyle:{background:bbl_bg,
            opacity:0.75,
            width:"320px"
          },
          closeBoxMargin:"2px 2px 2px 2px",
          closeBoxURL:myClose,
          infoBoxClearance:new google.maps.Size(1,1)
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,"click",function(){
          infobox.open(map,this);
          map.panTo(loc)
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**Current HTML** *includes an "info bubble"*

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></div>
<div class="infobox-wrapper">
    <div id="infobox">
        <h3>Publi Design inc.</h3>
        <p>
            505, rue Père-Daniel <br />
            Trois-Rivières (Québec) G9A 5Z7  <br /> <br />

            <a href="tel:8193734071">819 373.4071</a> | 
            imagination@publidesign.com
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Perhaps what I'm looking for is another function I haven't found, but I think this would come in handy when we try to see where the origin is and what's around it (landmarks, streets, etc.).

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wQM8z/1/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the end of your initialize routine (and add the button with id="reset"):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("reset"), 'click', function() {
    map.setCenter(loc);
    map.setZoom(15);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wQM8z/1/)

Comment: This is really cool, it uses the zoom AND move at the same time, real nice effect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `setCenter` and `setZoom` methods on the map at any time. If you want your map to "go back to origin", then all you need to be able to do is store your starting location and starting zoom level in variables that you can later access.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store it in a variable. Google Maps API doesn't provide you these settings.